# How to count a list of Enums by a predicate?

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have a list of:

```
var foos = new List<E_Foo>() { E_Foo.FooA, E_Foo.FooB , ... };
```

where `E_Foo` is:

```
public enum E_Foo
{
    Undefined = 0,
    FooA = 1,
    FooB = 2
}
```

I need to count the number of occurrences for a specific Enum value, for instance:

```
int fooACount = foos.Count(x => x.GetType() == E_Foo.FooA);
```

But it is show a compiler error of:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Type' and 'E_Foo'

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a complete example. We can't tell whether `E_Foo` is an enum itself with values of `FooA` and `FooB`, or whether `E_Foo.FooA` and `E_Foo.FooB` are the enums.

Comment: Hey @JonSkeet, see the updated question, I've added the definition for the `E_Foo` Enum

Comment: Right, that's much clearer - and spzvtbg's answer is basically what I'd have given. (As an aside, please be aware that a `E_` prefix is definitely not a normal .NET naming convention.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare them by value, not by type

```
foos.Count(x => x == E_Foo.FooA)
```

Comment: Just to support your answer, here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HWcdaB